# MYSQL+MyISAM+Need information regarding check table statement

Tags: mysql, restore, mysql-workbench

The [MySQL CHECK TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/check-table.html) statement checks a table or tables for errors.

Does the statement put an auto lock on a table before checking table for errors?

Does the statement perform a READ ONLY operation?

I have executed the CHECK TABLE command from MYSQL workbench (on same table copy/replication) operation going on,I got

`Lost connection to server during query`

error message for CHECK TABLE statement, [read timeout interval (in seconds):[30]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html)

Can this action can corrupt my copy/replication? (or because of data Copy/replication running on table, table is having auto lock ON so CHECK TABLE statement failed which is not going to impact copy operation). Please provide information so i will understand process better.

Answer (score 1):

Big table?  It should be read-only.  If it finds something, `CHECK TABLE` suggests that you run `REPAIR TABLE` -- which will modify the table.

Whenever the server crashes (power failure or whatever), `CHECK TABLE` is needed for MyISAM tables, but not for InnoDB tables.  I recommend you change Engines.

Since almost every action locks the whole table in MyISAM, I would guess that `CHECK` does, too.